# Angular 4 Firebase manipulate *ngFor of Observable or use index in an Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire

I am using Angular 4 with Firebase database.In my app I want to display on the browser a Leaderboard with the top ten users.
I am using this code on my component.ts

```
export class HomefillerComponent implements OnInit {
 topusers: Observable<any>;
  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase,public authService: AuthService) {


        this.topusers = db.list('users', {
        query: {
         orderByChild: "totalscore",
         limitToLast: 10,
        }
        }).map((topusers) => {console.log(topusers);
        return topusers.reverse();})

   }
```

And the html code:

```
<a class="btn btn-download  nav-item vlink  dropdown-toggle pointer " data-toggle="dropdown">Leaderboard</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu text-center list">
                                  <ul *ngFor="let topuser of topusers | async">
                                    <li> {{ topuser.username | json }}:{{ topuser.totalscore | json }} </li>
                                  </ul>
           </ul>
        </div>
```

Everything works fine and I get the first 10 users.However I want the results to be shown like this example:

```
<ul>
            <li><span>First:</span><span>Unknow</span></li>
            <li><span >Second:</span><span>Unknow</span></li>
            <li><span >Third:</span><span >Unknow</span></li>
            <li><span >Fourth:</span><span>Unknow</span></li>
            <li><span >Fifth</span><span>Unknow</span></li>
             ...etc...                    
</ul>
```

Where unknown would be replaced with the correct index of topusers observable. 
What I want is to control the `*ngFor="let topuser of topusers | async"` into 10 topusers so i can put the First,Second etc.. left on them. I searched almost everywhere but couldnt find any help on how to use specific Index on the Observable on the the html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the index variable of the ngFor directive

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of observable$ | async; let i = index">
     <li> {{i + 1 | ordinalString}} {{ topuser.username | json }}:{{ topuser.totalscore | json }} </li>
 </div>
```

Then run the index through a pipe to get the desired string.

```
@Pipe({name: 'ordinalString'})
export class OrdinalStringPipe implements PipeTransform {
    // super simple ordinal string method
    transform(index: number): string{
        let ordinalStrings = ['Zero', 'First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth', 'Fifth', 'Sixth', 'Seventh', 'Eighth', 'Ninth', 'Tenth'];

        return ordinalStrings[index];
    }
}
```

Here is a working plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/trvaibgJb9v2IKreN3uY?p=preview

Here is an article demoing the ngFor index variable: https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-ng-for-syntax